# Verify message was sent with Twilio - Python

Tags: python, sms

I have a small script that sends text messages with Twilio using Python.

This is my code:

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client
account_sid = os.environ.get('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID')
auth_token = os.environ.get('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN')
     client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
     cell_number = os.environ.get('CELL_PHONE_NUMBER')
     text_message = input("Enter a message to send: ")
     send_message = client.messages.create(from_=os.environ.get('TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER'),
                             to=cell_number,
                             body=text_message
      print(send_message)
```

And this is the response I get back:

```
<Twilio.Api.V2010.MessageInstance account_sid=MY_ACCOUNT_SID sid=SMc5e8f335198144b4b3c7f401af511f11>
```

I was wondering what the best way was to validate that the message was actually sent in code.

I thought of doing something like this:

```
if send_message:
    print("Message sent.")
else:
    print("Message not sent.")
```

And I was just wondering if there was a better way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that this is a relatively old question and you might have figured out a way to achieve the desired behavior, but just wanted to post my thoughts so that it may help other learners like me in the future.

So basically, twilio provides developers with a functionality of webhooks using which the status of messages can be tracked. You will have to provide an extra parameter while creating the message wherein you will have to pass the callback url pointing to a server which will be logging the status of the sent messages.

When your python script sends a SMS by doing a POST request to twilio server, twilio will send the status of the message to the callback URL as a parameter by making a post or a get request.

This [document](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-confirm-delivery-python) describes how to achieve the above behavior with the help of example code snippets. In case you used another method to track the status of the messages, let us know so that it will help the community.